# Cut sub-string and rename files use shell command

Tags: shell

How to rename file names?  I want to map names:

```
abc-hdpi.png ⟶ abc.png
bcd-hdpi.png ⟶ bcd.png
```

...

I have many files to do this, so `mv abc-hdpi.png abc.png` is not a good solution.

Comment: What is it that you want to remove, more specifically? Are all files named `*-hdpi.png`, or do you want to remove everything after a dash?

Comment: Yes, all files named `*-hdpi.png`,  and I want to discard `-hdpi`, and rename to `*.png`. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Search for `prename` (Perl `rename`) command; it can do the job easily:

```
prename 's/-hdpi.png/.png/' *-hdpi.png
```

Failing that:

```
for file in *-hdpi.png
do
    mv "$file" "${file%-hdpi.png}.png"
done
```

Comment: Yeah, that's better.

Comment: `prename` not work,  terminal tells `substitution replacement not terminated at (eval 1) line 1`

Comment: `for do done` works, thanks : )

Comment: I'm puzzled about `prename` not working if you have it on the machine.  You did include the single quotes, didn't you?  I'm glad that the `for` loop worked as a fallback.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract from a fixed length string like so:

```
NAME[0]="abc-hdpi.png"
NAME[1]="def-hdpi.png"
NAME[2]="ghi-hdpi.png"
NAME[3]="jkl-hdpi.png"
NAME[4]="mno-hdpi.png"

rename(){
    var=$1
    mv $var $var{0:2}$var{8:}
}

for i in "${Name[@]}"
do
    rename $i
done
```

Comment: The `$var = $1` does not work; no spaces around `=` in shell assignments, and no `$` before the name on the LHS of the assignment.  Can't you use a loop to iterate over the array?

Comment: thanks, changed $var to var

Comment: FYI, you could initialize the array with: `NAME=("abc-hdpi.png"
"def-hdpi.png"
"ghi-hdpi.png"
"jkl-hdpi.png"
"mno-hdpi.png")`.

Comment: I'm very sorry for ambiguous description, the prefix is not fixed length. so your answer may not suitable for this case. Thanks a lot for your immediately answer. :)